# npm ERR npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ejs":"2.6.1"

Tags: node.js, npm

i have deleted nodeJs ad re-install it again and i used npm cache clean --force and didn't work and i used npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ nothing worked

please help me with this if someone fixed the same error before

//the ERR

```
npm ERR! file E:\Courses\Express\project\nodeauth\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ejs":"2.6.1"
npm ERR! JSON.parse   }
npm ERR! JSON.parse     '
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OmarBaz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-23T18_04_08_578Z-debug.log
```

//here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "inside",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "*",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-messages": "*",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "*",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "multer": "*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-http": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "pug": "2.0.3",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "ejs":"2.6.1"
  }
```

Comment: Could you paste here `E:\Courses\Express\project\nodeauth\package.json`? This file contains error.

Comment: here is my package.json file

Comment: There is no `}` at the end.